# ngx-translate in angular material input not showing the translation on initial load but shows it after that

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate v10.02 in my Angular 6 app and using material 6.4

I have a very annoying issue, where the value is shown without translation on initial load, but then if I change language back & forth it will appear translated

My code is like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="{{'IDType'| translate}}" disabled name="idType" 
  [(ngModel)]="this.dataService.idType" 
  value="{{this.dataService.idType | translate}}">
    </mat-form-field>
```

So on initial load it will show the variable itself without translation (i.e value of `this.dataService.idType`) but then it translates if I change language, I wonder what causes that.

Can anyone advise on what I have missed here?

Update:

All other translated elements are shown correctly on initial load except that one shown above, the difference I see is that this is the only element to have a variable to be translated, all others are static fields

That field is a variable that is changed between two values so I can't replace it with static value, but since it is translated after changing language I feel it is doable but a small thing is missing to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the issue, I hope this helps someone else

The value that was loaded initially in the input field was of the

```
[(ngModel)]="this.dataService.idType"
```

Then it was overwritten with the translated value when I change language, so the solution in my case was to remove the ngModel & depend only on the value field which has the translation & loads it correctly on initial load, so the code will be like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="{{'IDType'| translate}}" disabled name="idType" 
  value="{{this.dataService.idType | translate}}">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is an initial language set on load? In app.component or whatever you bootstrap. this.translateService.use('en') or whatever default language you want.

sucha as:

```
export class AppComponent {
param = {value: 'world'};

constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

     // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    translate.use('en');
}
```

Comment: Yes I am sure, actually all other translated elements are shown correctly except that one, but that is the only element to have a variable to be translated , all others are static fields

Comment: have you tried

placeholder="{{IDType| translate}}" and make sure IDType is a string.

Comment: Actually the placeholder itself is working fine on initial load but the value field doesn't work

Comment: Could be that the value is not initialized when the page is painted? Try storing in local object on inInit and then use that instead of this.dataservice etc.. See if that works

Comment: That is a good idea, but unfortunately the variable contains a value on page initialization , when I console log the value inside ngOnInit() , I find a value (the same the shall be translated, which already appears)

Strangely when I set the variable to one value it appears translated as it should

Btw, that variable is set in the shared service in a previous component so I think that shall not be a problem (the variable is initialized I mean before loading the component)